# Reemplazar caracteres en Java

Tags: java

Quiero reemplazar los caracteres en java de una palabra:

```
Hol?a por -> Hol a 

private String escapaCaracter(String valor) {

String valorOk = " ";
try {
      valorOk = valor
                .replaceAll("/", "-")
                .replaceAll("\\\\", " ")
                .replaceAll("¿", " ")
                .replaceAll("?", " ")
                .replaceAll("#", " ")
                .replaceAll("<", " ")
                .replaceAll(">", " ")
                .replaceAll("[", " ")
                .replaceAll("]", " ")
                .replaceAll("{", " ")
                .replaceAll("}", " ");
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (s_log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
        s_log.log(Level.FINEST, "Ha fallado el escapaCaracter para el valor: " + valor);
    }
}

    return valorOk;
}
```

El problema es que aunque no lleve ningún de esos caracteres falla ->

Valor con el que estaba probando -> pro

error ->

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?
^
```

Estos caracteres corresponden a unos valores que cuando se monta una url podría ocasionar fallos, lo digo por **si alguien conoce más caracteres** que podrían dar fallos, es decir :

parametro1= hol/a ;

Al montar la url aparecería -> `http://...hol/a/param2...`
Se pretende dejar un espacio en blanco ->
valor = hol/a ;
 -> `http://...hol a/param2...`

Comment: `.replaceAll("\?", " ")`  prueba a poner `\ ` antes del carácter especifico `?`. Algunos caracteres son usados en expresiones regulares y para que sean literales necesitaras `\ `

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) da ese error el eclipse

Comment: perdona son 2 barras : `\\ `  sería: `.replaceAll("\\?", " ")`

Answer (score 1):

Utilice lo siguiente para reemplazar todos los caracteres especiales de una sola vez:

Para mantener los carácteres alphanúmericos:

```
valorOk = valor.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"," ");
```

Para solo los caracteres alphabetichos:

```
valorOk = valor.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

De esta forma ahorra muchas lineas de código y lo hace de una sola vez

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de una url lo mejor sería usar `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(urlString)`.

Por lo demás, si buscas los caracteres que te pueden dar este error deberías mirar el código de `java.util.regex.Pattern`, ahí está el error *Dangling meta character*. Solo como adelanto - los caracteres que te van a dar el error son **?, *, +**. A parte de estos hay unos cuantos más que no sirven para patrones.

Insisto, si es para evitar problemas en url mejor `URLEncoder`.